# Error: tasksel install lamp-server

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, lamp

I'm having trouble using tasksel to install lamp-server on ubuntu 12.04. Here's the error:

```
Can't call method "set" on an undefined value at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd.pm line 126, <GEN0> line 5.
tasksel: aptitude failed (255)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently tasksel is depreciated for things like this - try `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` instead. This does seem to appear in [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.5/+bug/1133892) and [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1660308), but I can't seem to find anyone who has *fixed* this issue.